# React checkbox default check first item in mapping array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I have a little problem with checkbox in JSX when I want to have a default value in checkbox
I want to have a default value and changing the state onChange and default checks the first value of the array.

this code is what i tried :

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export const checkbox = () => {

    const array = [
        {
            id: 0,
            value: 100,
            unit: 'gram',
            price: 20000
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            value: 150,
            unit: 'gram',
            price: 23536
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            value: 590,
            unit: 'gram',
            price: 56700
        }
    ]

    const [value, setValue] = useState({});


    return (
        <div id="checkbox">
            {
                array.map((data) => 
                    (
                        <label>
                            <span>{data.value} - {data.price}</span>
                            <input type="radio" defaultChecked={true} onChange={e => setValue(data)} />
                        </label>
                    )
                )
            }
        </div>
    )

}
```

Comment: Didn't get what you're asking for?

Comment: i need to first element of array.map gets checked and be able to have onChange function which it doesn't work in my code

Comment: Still didn't get what you're asking and trying to do!! :-(